# Why is the first SQL row repeated on each line?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm not sure what I am missing.  I am running a SQL query for the first 10 rows.  I am outputting them to Tkinter Entrys.  Why is only the first SQL row displaying in each Entry such as self.output1 and self.output2?
I want each SQL row to display in each Tkinter Entry.

```
import os
import pypyodbc
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import BOTH, END, LEFT


class Adder(ttk.Frame):
    """The adders gui and functions."""
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.root = parent
        self.init_gui()


    def calculate(self):
        firstname = str(self.first_entry.get())
        lastname = str(self.last_entry.get())     
        license = str(self.lic_entry.get())
        if (firstname and not lastname and not license):  # "You entered first name."

            try:
                connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=ENTERSERVERNAME;Database=ENTERDATABASENAME;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
            except pypyodbc.Error as ex:
                sqlstate = ex.args[0]
                if sqlstate == '28000':
                    self.answer_label['text'] = "You do not have access." 
            cursor = connection.cursor() 
            SQLCommand = ("SELECT LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, L_LICNUMBER "      
                "FROM dbo.ENTERTABLENAME "   # table name
                "with (nolock)"
                "WHERE FIRSTNAME = ?")
            Values = [firstname]
            cursor.execute(SQLCommand,Values)
            results = cursor.fetchmany(10)
            if results:
                self.output0.insert(0,results[0])
                self.output1.insert(0,results[1])
                self.output2.insert(0,results[2])
                self.output3.insert(0,results[3])
                self.output4.insert(0,results[4])
                self.output5.insert(0,results[5])
                self.output6.insert(0,results[6])
                self.output7.insert(0,results[7])
                self.output8.insert(0,results[8])
                self.output9.insert(0,results[9])
                connection.close()


    def init_gui(self):
        """Builds GUI."""

        self.root.option_add('*tearOff', 'FALSE')

        self.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew') # this starts the entire form


# Input Boxes and Button

        self.first_entry = tkinter.Entry(self, width=28) # first input box
        self.first_entry.grid(sticky='', column=1, row=1) 

        self.last_entry = tkinter.Entry(self, width=28) # second input box
        self.last_entry.grid(sticky='', column=2, row=1) 

        self.lic_entry = tkinter.Entry(self, width=28) # third input box
        self.lic_entry.grid(sticky='', column=3, row=1) 


        self.calc_button = ttk.Button(self, text='Search', command=self.calculate) # button
        self.calc_button.grid(column=4, row=1, columnspan=1, sticky='w', padx=14)

        # Output frame for answers

        self.output0 = tkinter.Entry(self, width=150, text=' ', bd=0,)
        self.output0.grid(column=0, row=6, columnspan=5, padx=100, pady=0)
        self.output1 = tkinter.Entry(self, width=150, text=' ', bd=0,)
        self.output1.grid(column=0, row=7, columnspan=5, padx=100, pady=0)
        self.output2 = tkinter.Entry(self, width=150, text=' ', bd=0,)
        self.output2.grid(column=0, row=8, columnspan=5, padx=100, pady=0)
        self.output3 = tkinter.Entry(self, width=150, text=' ', bd=0,)
        self.output3.grid(column=0, row=9, columnspan=5, padx=100, pady=0)
        self.output4 = tkinter.Entry(self, width=150, text=' ', bd=0,)
        self.output4.grid(column=0, row=10, columnspan=5, padx=100, pady=0)
        self.output5 = tkinter.Entry(self, width=150, text=' ', bd=0,)
        self.output5.grid(column=0, row=11, columnspan=5, padx=100, pady=0)
        self.output6 = tkinter.Entry(self, width=150, text=' ', bd=0,)
        self.output6.grid(column=0, row=12, columnspan=5, padx=100, pady=0)
        self.output7 = tkinter.Entry(self, width=150, text=' ', bd=0,)
        self.output7.grid(column=0, row=13, columnspan=5, padx=100, pady=0)
        self.output8 = tkinter.Entry(self, width=150, text=' ', bd=0,)
        self.output8.grid(column=0, row=14, columnspan=5, padx=100, pady=0)
        self.output9 = tkinter.Entry(self, width=150, text=' ', bd=0,)
        self.output9.grid(column=0, row=15, columnspan=5, padx=100, pady=0)       
        self.blank = tkinter.LabelFrame(self, height=10, width=620, text=' ', bd=0,) # blank line
        self.blank.grid(column=0, row=16, columnspan=5, padx=100, pady=0)      

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    Adder(root)
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False) # locks window from being resized
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried `print(results)` to see if the results of the query are what you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the entry widget option `text` is just an abbreviation for `textvariable`; the entry widget has no `text` option. That means that every widget is sharing the same textvariable. Because they are all tied to the same `textvariable` the will all share the same value. Thus, when you insert text into one, it gets inserted into all.

The solution is to remove `text=' '` from every place where you create an `Entry` widget.

Comment: Thank, I'll try and explain it better next time.